# Not sure why I am getting an exception when trying to call my method

Tags: java, exception

Ok so the I am supposed to place a battleship on the board using exceptions to make sure no rules are broken. Yet when I try and call the function I am getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception
    at BattleshipBoard.main(BattleshipBoard.java:135)
```

Not 100% sure what I am doing wrong, if you guys could identify what is wrong and the associated rule that I am apparently breaking it would be highly appreciated.

here is the relevant code:

```
public void placeShip(int startCol, int startRow, int endCol, int endRow)
        throws Exception {
            if(startCol > numCols) {
                throw new Exception("0");
            }
            if(startCol < 0 ) {
                throw new Exception("Out of bounds, less than 1(startCol)");
            }
            if (startRow > numRows) {
                throw new Exception("Out of bounds, Greater then numRows");
            }
            if (startRow < 0) {
                throw new Exception("Out of bounds, less than 1 (startRow)");
            }
            if((startCol != endCol) && (startRow != endRow)){
                throw new Exception("Diag");
            }
            if(board[i][j] == 1){
                throw new Exception("Overlap");
            }
            if (startCol == endCol){
                for (i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++ ){
                    board[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }
            if (startRow == endRow){
                for(j = startRow; j <= endRow; j++){
                    board[i][j] = 1;
                }
            }


}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // You may leave this empty
    BattleshipBoard b = new BattleshipBoard(10, 10);
    b.placeShip(0, 0, 3, 0);
}
```

Comment: Please post the "main" method code.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't handling the exception that placeShip can throw.  You should place the placeShip call inside of a try block

```
try{
b.placeShip(0, 0, 3, 0);
}
catch(Exception x){
// take some action
}
```

That way if placeShip throws an exception your program doesn't just crash.

Comment: I can't just put a try catch block around the method call. The person who will be reviewing my code is using an automatic driver, so I need to figure out why I am getting this exception and how to avoid it in the future.

Comment: then place the try catch around the method call and see what happens. i.e. which exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Java has checked exceptions. make this:

```
try {
 b.placeShip(0, 0, 3, 0);
} catch(Exception e) {
System.err.println("error: "+e.getMessage());
}
```

However, it is not a good idea to use `Exception`. Better create your own exceptions which extend `Exception` This way you can handle different rule violations accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[Checked exceptions should either be catched or re-thrown.](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=129) So, you have 2 options

1. Declare main(..) method to throw Exception or
2. sorround b.placeShip(...) with try-catch

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need these for loops?

```
        if (startCol == endCol){
            for (i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++ ){
                board[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
        if (startRow == endRow){
            for(j = startRow; j <= endRow; j++){
                board[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
```

If the initial value is equal to the final value the loop will only execute once anyway. Just do:

```
board[startCol][j] = 1;
board[i][startRow] = 1;
```

I also suspect that you're getting an "index array out of bounds exception" in this part of the code.

Comment: I used the for loops because if say someone has a battleship n spaces long. Then the loops will go through and mark each spot where the ship is as 1, which on a tile stands for a ship there. Where 0 is nothing and 3 is a hit ship.

Comment: @Jeff Andrews: It's not working as you expect. Since the loops only execute if the startCol == endCol, then they will only execute once because those are the ends of the loop "space".

Comment: @Tudor I designed it that way because you can not place a battleship diagonally. So that piece of code is to ensure that the battleships are either vertical or horizontal. Is my problem that the startCol/startRow is larger than the endCol/endRow, thus I should do i-- not i++?

Comment: The problem is that your loops are useless. You start from a value X and go to a value Y but only execute the loop if X == Y. Can you see what happens here?

Comment: Ahhhh I see what you are talking about there. If startCol == endCol then the ship is obviously vertical so I need to use startRow and endRow in my loops?